# D3 vertical line beetween grouped chart bars spacing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph

The problem:

The number of groups is dynamic, and vertical line (separator) needs dynamic padding. Group width im getting with **x0.rangeBand()**. Is there any way to get width of space beetween two groups dynamically?

Peace of code:

```
.....

    var slice = svg.selectAll(".chart")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "g")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + x0(d.category) + ",0)";
        });



    // Create rectangles of the correct width
    slice.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d.values;
        })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x1(d.rate);
        })
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.rate)
        })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(0);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
            return height - y(0);
        })
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.rgb(color(d.rate)).darker(2));
            tip.show(d);

        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {
            tip.hide
            d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.rate));
        })

    slice.append("line")
        .attr("class", "blabla")
        .attr("x1", x0.rangeBand()+20)
        .attr("x2", x0.rangeBand()+20)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("stroke", "#000");
.....
```

This is how it looks with few groups

[image]

This is how it looks with many groups
[image]

Comment: what if you set a `paddingInner()` to your `x0()` and draw the lines in the middle of this gap?

Comment: v3 does not have paddingInner() function.. https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md#ordinal

Comment: the `0.1` in `rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);` is the padding. I had to guess without full source code. What was needed was to add the space size in the calculation.

Comment: I have bookmarked the d3 API link. Might be useful for d3 examples.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because I see no reason why to stick to d3v3 and I can't find the d3v3 documentation easily for ordinal scales here is a d3v5 version of the code with correct placement of the vertical bars. You have to use the bandwidth and the step to calculate the position.

It is an adaptation of the example in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571302/d3-bar-label-on-grouped-chart-bar) : https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad

I doubled the number of groups and it looks nice.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
           .rangeRound([0, width])
           .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand();

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x0)
    .tickSize(0);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#ca0020","#f4a582","#d5d5d5","#92c5de","#0571b0"]);

var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("barchart.json", {credentials: 'same-origin'}).then(function(data) {

  var categoriesNames = data.map(function(d) { return d.categorie; });
  var rateNames = data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; });

  x0.domain(categoriesNames);
  x1.domain(rateNames).range([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(categorie) { return d3.max(categorie.values, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .style('opacity','0')
      .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style('font-weight','bold')
      .text("Value");

  svg.select('.y').transition().duration(500).delay(1300).style('opacity','1');

  var slice = svg.selectAll(".slice")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.categorie) + ",0)"; });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
  .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.rate); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.rate) })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(0); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(0); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", d3.rgb(color(d.rate)).darker(2));
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.select(this).style("fill", color(d.rate));
      });

  slice.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function (d) {return Math.random()*1000;})
      .duration(1000)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

slice.append("line")
        .attr("class", "blabla")
        .attr("x1", (x0.step() - x0.bandwidth())*0.5 + x0.bandwidth())
        .attr("x2", (x0.step() - x0.bandwidth())*0.5 + x0.bandwidth())
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("stroke", "#000");

  //Legend
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(data[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.rate; }).reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity","0");

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); });

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) {return d; });

  legend.transition().duration(500).delay(function(d,i){ return 1300 + 100 * i; }).style("opacity","1");

});
```

Comment: Im depended on other graphs. And they are in v3, so i can not easily upgrade it. But I founda solution with your help for v3. Thank you

Comment: The conversion from v3 to v5 just took me a few minutes so maybe you might consider porting all the other graphs to the latest D3.

Answer (score 0):

So the trick is to recalculate padding self. V3 does not have band.step() function so I added this method to get the middle of two items:

```
function getMiddle(x0){

    var rng = x0.range();
    var band = x0.rangeBand();
    var padding = 0;

    if(rng.length>1){
        padding = (rng[1]-rng[0] - band) *0.5;
    }
    return band + padding;
}
```

And usage:

```
    slice.append("line")
        .attr("x1", getMiddle(x0))
        .attr("x2", getMiddle(x0))
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .style("stroke-width", 1)
        .style("stroke", "#000");
```

Comment: the `step()` is the distance between successive domain entries: `x0(x0.domain()[1]) - x0(x0.domain()[0])`. I think the `x0.range()` includes the outer padding.

Comment: the confusion was caused by the fact that the range is specified as an interval `[0,width]` but when you call `x0.range()` (v3) you get back the whole list of discrete values of the range. In v5 `x0.range()` just returns the **interval**, I don't think there is an equivalent in v5 of the v3 result other then `map()` yourself.