# d3 bar label on grouped chart bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, graph

Im using this example - https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad

and trying to add adittional infromation on the bars.

I tried:

```
    slice.selectAll("rect").append("text")
        .attr("class", 'bar-text')
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.total;
        })
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            var x0 = x1.rangeBand() * i + 11,
                y0 = y + 8;
            return "translate(" + x0 + "," + y0 + ")";
        })
```

But text elements appends to inner rect element and it is not visible:

```
<g class="g" transform="translate(46,0)">
    <rect width="101" x="2" style="fill: rgb(8, 81, 156);" y="150.00000000000003" height="300">
        <text class="bar-text" fill="#000" transform="translate(11,function u(n){return o(n)}8)"></text>
    </rect>
    <rect width="101" x
    ...
```

**slice.append...** selects only groups unfortunately too. Any ideas how to append text element on this example to bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your screenshot, the `translate` attribute contains `function u(n)....`. The variable y is a function not the value of the rect Y-coord. To get that you need `d3.select(this).attr("y")`. But then the text is also not visible I used `y(d.value)` but that is equivalent.

You have to add the texts just like the rects.

This you need to add to the d3v5 code I posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51573685/9938317

The text does not animate yet, use the same animation code as for the rect Y-coord. Or create the text at the end of the rect animation.

```
slice.selectAll("text")
      .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", 'bar-text')
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) { return d.value; })
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return x1.bandwidth() * (i+0.5); })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) { return y(d.value) + 8; });
```

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm! I needed to use only x1.rangeBand() in place of x1.bandwidth()  in v3.